# How to start rails server localhost:3000 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, command

i am beginner at ruby on rails.

I did everything on the official page. (http://rubyonrails.org/download)

And i try to start new project but the localhost doest not work on ubuntu 12.04.

I use these command:

```
rails new /home/mehmet/Desktop/test/
```

Here is the console output:

```
create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:254: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:263: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.9) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.9) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.9) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.9) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.9) 
Using activeresource (3.2.9) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.9) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using rails (3.2.9) 
Using sass (3.2.4) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

do you have any idea? how i can create a new project and how i can see the localhost:3000 ?

Edit:

i think, my problem is about the server.

i use **rails s** command to start server and it takes some errors:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/testtt/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
mehmet@vefanet:~/Desktop/testtt$ rails s -p 3005 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/testtt/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
mehmet@vefanet:~/Desktop/testtt$ rails s
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/mehmet/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/testtt/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Check your config/database.yml username and password,  and verify your ruby and rails version.

Comment: And also check folder permission is equal to 777

Comment: i cant find the config folder and database.myl file. i had install mysql before rails. because i was using php+mysql. what do u think, is it about the config file? and how can i find the config file??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd /home/mehmet/Desktop/test/

bundle install

rails s
```

Answer (score 4):

You already have your answer:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)

Easiest way to fix - just install nodejs on your box - `apt-get install nodejs` on ubuntu.

Comment: i did it, **pt-get install nodejs** command, there is no error line, but the server still not working??

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

Use following command to run in default port **3000**

```
bundle install
rails s
```

If you want run in specific port number then use following,

```
rails s -p 3005
```